# How to check if Out of office is enabled, and if disabled, enable it

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to build an integration with our account termination process. On termination, set out of office it has not been set yet.

What to I put in the public main() to run - if  IsOutOfOfficeSet is not set, then do nothing and it set then run SetOutofOffice.
Otherwise, if anyone has better codes to check if out of office is set, if set then ignore, otherwise set it?

```
class Script : ScriptBase
{

    const bool bTest = false;   //set to true to not set OOF
    const bool bDebug = false;  //set to true for more logging
    ExchangeResource2010 exchange = ProvisioningSystem.Organisation.Resources["Exchange Servers"] as ExchangeResource2010;

    public void main()
    {
    }

    public bool IsOutOfOfficeSet(UserDirectoryEntry user)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            foreach (PSObject o in exchange.Exec("Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration", "Identity", user.DomainName, "DomainController", user.ServerName))
            {

                string autoReplyState = o.Properties["AutoReplyState"].Value.ToString();
                DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(o.Properties["StartTime"].Value);
                DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(o.Properties["EndTime"].Value);


                if (bDebug)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("AutoReplyState={0}", autoReplyState));
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("StartTime={0}", startTime));
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("EndTime={0}", endTime));

                    if (Job != null)
                        Job.LogAudit("AutoReplyConfiguration", sb.ToString());
                    else
                        Trace.WriteLine("AutoReplyConfiguration\r\n" + sb.ToString());
                }


                if (String.Compare(autoReplyState, "Disabled") == 0)
                    return false;

                if (String.Compare(autoReplyState, "Enabled") == 0)
                    return true;

                if (String.Compare(autoReplyState, "Scheduled") == 0)
                {

                    //If scheduled OOO has not ended then return true
                    if (endTime > DateTime.Now)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving auto reply configuration for " + user.DomainName, ex);

        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Setoutofoffice(UserDirectoryEntry user)
    {

        //Out of office should be termination date plus 30 days
        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); //end out of office within 30 days from today

        string message = Evaluator.GetString(Job, "=//Job/Task/OOOMessage");
        LogAudit("Scheduling out of office for {0} from {1} to {2}", user, fromDate, toDate);

        ExchangeResource exchange = ProvisioningSystem.Organisation.Resources["Exchange Servers"] as ExchangeResource;
        if (exchange == null) throw new Exception("Exchange resource is NULL");
        ((ExchangeResource2010)exchange).ExecNoResults("Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration", "Identity", user.EmailAddress, "AutoReplyState", "Scheduled", "StartTime", fromDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "EndTime", toDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "Confirm", false, "-InternalMessage", message, "ExternalMessage", message, "ExternalAudience", "All", "DomainController", user.ServerName);


    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to write?

```
public void main()
{
    if(!IsOutOfOfficeSet(user)){
        Setoutofoffice(user);
    }
}
```

Where user is a valid `UserDirectoryEntry` object

Comment: Thanks heaps Char. It ran, but i think my OutOfOfficeSet is incorrect. It is returning the exception error? Any ideas? Thanks Char.

Comment: @MichelleNZ Also don't forget to mark answers as correct if they answer your question :) It will give both users points and sets your question as resolved!

Comment: The error is:Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Script Line: 81: throw new Exception("Error retrieving auto reply configuration f

Comment: It works now. Thank you. i will mark this as complete. Thanks so much Char!

Comment: @MichelleNZ Glad you got it sorted out! No problem